# Recreating Javascript/Underscore reduce using a custom .each callback

Tags: javascript, callback, underscore.js

I am trying to build Javascript/Underscore .reduce method using a .each function that I built as a callback.

I want to ensure that .reduce function is general enough to work not just in the example that I included, but will work anywhere the Underscore .reduce works.

Here is where I currently am.  Any feedback is appreciated.  Thanks!

```js
    var list =[1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var objList = {name:'mike', color:"blue", hair:"brown"};
    
    //.each function
    function each(list, callback) {
     //console.log(list.constructor==="Object");
     if(list.constructor===Object) {
      for (var key in list) {
       callback(list[key]);
      }
     }
     else if (list.constructor===Array) {
      //console.log("Array")
      for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
       callback(list[i]);
      }
     }
    }
    
    //.reduce function
    function reduce(list,startVal,accumulator) {
     var total;
     each(list, function(accumulator) {
      total=accumulator;
     })
     return total
    } 
    //test accumulator function
    function printTwo(val) {
     return val;
    } 
    alert(reduce(list, 0, printTwo));
    alert(reduce(objList, 0, printTwo));
```

Comment: You are aware that [`.reduce()` is already available on `Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), right?

Comment: So does your code work? (and putting aside the question of why you are doing this in the first place) If not, what's the problem? If it does, then this looks like a better fit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jmar777: Not to mention [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I'm assuming this is an academic exercise for the OP?

Comment: Also, I would think that your `accumulator` that you pass to `reduce` would have to take both the current value and the accumulated value in order to be able to do anything useful with it.

Comment: Hi guys, the code is not working.  I am working on this to gain a deeper understanding on array methods, callbacks and Underscore.

Comment: @MattBurland can you show me an example of what you mean?  Thanks.

Comment: @mferg: I think the documentation for `.reduce` on MDN is good enough for an example. The callback takes `previousValue`, `currentValue`, `index` and `array`. The first two are vital for the functioning of a reduce function. The last two are nice to have.